# Ember input blur action

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How can i trigger an action on input blur, this is what i have tried.

```
{{input class="form-control" action="validateEmail" onEvent="onBlur"}}
{{input class="form-control" action="validateEmail" onEvent="blur"}}
{{input class="form-control" action="validateEmail" onEvent="focusOut"}}
```

They all only trigger on enter

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the `focus-out`

```
{{input type="text" value=text focus-out="doAction"}}
```

Give a look in that fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/977xj/

Comment: @Marcio Junior
is it possible with only focus-out??? I tried key-up, click etc but your style doesnt work. Also is it possible to have more than one event registered through action? my way usually is {{input value=text action="kk" on="focus-out"}}
Also how do you pass parameters in this method? Usually it is <input {{action 'actionName' params}}/>

Answer (score 5):

To pass arguments to an action, you can use closure action syntax:

```
{{input focus-out=(action "doSomething" "someArgument")}}
```

- http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_closure-actions
- http://alexdiliberto.com/posts/ember-closure-actions/

*(would've added this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation yet)*